# How to use soap api to get the data from Volocommerce api?

Tags: soap

How I can get the data from  [volocommerce api](https://www.volocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Volo-API-Guide-v1.7a.pdf)? If I have to use **getFullProductsByFields** service then volo says we have to use soap method to get the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from volo support. We can fetch the products information using their API.

https://direct4x4.esellerpro.com/eSellerProAPI/docs/#!/product/get_products

Thanks